# How to iterate through Coordinates in OnBindViewHolder when using RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to build an activity where I will display the location of devices based on the locations set using a RecyclerView. I am able to retrieve the values successfully from the database an plot a map. However, the map only displays the location of the first entry that is received. I have tried to search for a way to loop through but I am unable to solve the problem. Could anyone help me out?

Below is my code for the RecyclerAdapter that I am using to populate the RecyclerView.

**RequestsAdapter.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bloodconnect.Model.Requests;
import com.bloodconnect.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class RequestsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RequestsAdapter.RequestsViewHolder> {


    private Context mCtx;
    private List<Requests> requestsList;

    //getting the context and product list with constructor
    public RequestsAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Requests> requestsList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.requestsList = requestsList;

    }

    @Override
    public RequestsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //inflating and returning our view holder
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_card, null);
        return new RequestsViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RequestsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //getting the product of the specified position
        Requests requests = requestsList.get(position);

        //binding the data with the viewholder views
        holder.name.setText(requests.getName());
        holder.blood_group.setText(requests.getBlood_group());
        holder.date_of_request.setText(requests.getDate_of_request());
        holder.address.setText(requests.getAddress());

        holder.location = requests.getLat_lng();

        String[] arrayString = holder.location.split(",");

        holder.lat = arrayString[0];
        holder.lng = arrayString[1];

        holder.latf = Float.parseFloat(holder.lat);
        holder.lngf = Float.parseFloat(holder.lng);

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return requestsList.size();
    }


    class RequestsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnMapReadyCallback {

        TextView name, blood_group, date_of_request, lat_lng, address, latitude, longitude;
        GoogleMap mMap;
        MapView mMapView;

        String lat, lng, location;
        Float latf, lngf;

        public RequestsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.show_request_name);
            blood_group = itemView.findViewById(R.id.show_request_bloodgroup);
            date_of_request = itemView.findViewById(R.id.show_request_date);
            address = itemView.findViewById(R.id.show_request_address);

            mMapView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_map_view);

            if (mMapView != null)
            {
                mMapView.onCreate(null);
                mMapView.onResume();
                mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

            MapsInitializer.initialize(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
            mMap = googleMap;

            mMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
            GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions().liteMode(true);

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latf, lngf);
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions();
            marker.position(latLng);
            marker.title("test");
            googleMap.addMarker(marker);
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get the coordinates for the respective entries in the view?